# Querying Mysql and Echoing Drop down Selection

Tags: php, mysql, dropdownbox

I have built a form that has text fields, text areas, radio buttons, and drop downs, and I've created a query to pull the data from the database at the appropriate row, but can't figure out how to program the drop down to reflect the choice that's in the mysql row.  Here are a sample of the fields I've been able to program correctly:

```
<label for="contactname">Contact Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="contactname" value="<?php echo $query['contactname']; ?>"

<label for="delay">Delay:</label>
<input id="Yes"  type="radio" name="delay" value="Y" <?php if($query['delay']==='Y') echo 'checked'; ?> >Yes 
<input id="No" type="radio" name="delay" value="N" <?php if($query['delay']==='N') echo 'checked'; ?> >No

<label for="notes">Notes: </label>
<textarea name="notes" id="notes"><?php echo $query['notes']; ?></textarea>
```

These have all worked in pulling data from the mysql database correctly, but I'm trying to figure out how to program the drop downs so that when this form is pulled, the selection populates/displays the selected value when the form is pulled:

```
<label for="day">Select Option:</label>
<select name="day"> 
     <option value="0">Monday </option>
     <option value="1">Tuesday </option>
     <option value="2">Wednesday </option>
     <option value="3">Thursday </option>
     <option value="4">Friday </option>
</select>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The for attribute of a label needs to be the **id** of an element, not the name. Each radio button should have its own label. Use a fieldset + legend to label the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append " selected" to the option you want pre-selected in the dropdown.

```
<label for="day">Select Option:</label>
<select name="day"> 
 <option value="0"<?php if ($query['day'] == 0) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Monday</option>
 <option value="1"<?php if ($query['day'] == 1) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Tuesday</option>
 <option value="2"<?php if ($query['day'] == 2) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Wednesday </option>
 <option value="3"<?php if ($query['day'] == 3) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Thursday</option>
 <option value="4"<?php if ($query['day'] == 4) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Friday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That does indeed make it more cross-browser compatible; edited to reflect suggestion.

Comment: yea now should do what he wants it to do.

Answer (score -1):

try this example:

```
 //array as an example
 $your_db_array = array ('value1','value2','value3');

 // Make the pull-down menu:
 echo '<select name="pull_down">';
 foreach ($your_db_array as $key => $value) {
echo "<option value=\"$key\"";
// Check for stickyness:
if (isset($value_from_DB['value']) && ($value_from_DB['value'] == $key) ){ 
       echo ' selected="selected"';}
echo ">$value</option></select>";
}
```